# Always Include Certain Records in Daterange

Tags: sql, tableau-api

Sorry if this is too general a question, but I couldn't find much material on this.

I'm wondering if there is any way in SQL or Tableau to always include certain records despite changes in a date range?

For example, I have 200 records that range from 1940-2004 and want 2 or 3 of these records to always be returned in the query (which includes a date range statement) is there a known method?

I'd like to avoid altering the date attributes based on the date range statement itself is possible.

Initial data:

```
Person_ID  | Group   | Date
ID 1          2       1-1-2003
ID 2          1       1-1-1994
ID 3          1       1-1-1985
ID 4          1       1-1-1992
ID 5          2       1-1-1991
ID 6          2       1-1-2002
ID 7          1       1-1-2003
ID 8          2       1-1-2005
ID 9          2       1-1-1999
ID 10                 1-1-2002
ID 11                 1-1-1989
```

For my results, I want it to be possible so that no matter the daterange I select, ID 10 and ID 11 are included.

```
SELECT Person_ID
FROM table
WHERE DATE BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Will always yield ID 10 and ID 11 no matter the dates inputted.

Comment: Perhaps you could supply sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about tableau but you can try this...

```
SELECT Person_ID
FROM table
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN date1 AND date2) OR Person_ID = 10 OR Person_ID = 11
```

If you want help on figuring out queries try and say what you want as literal as possible using sql words.  So in this case you could say **"I want to select the person_id from table where the date is between date1 and date2 or if the person_id is 10 or if the person_id is 11"**.  If you ever say but **(ex: date between date1 and date2 but if their id is 10 then also do it)** then most likely you can put an or there : ).  So if I were to do it without the or it sound more normal (in my opinion at least -> **"where the date is between date1 and date2 but if the person_id is 10 or 11 also include it"**).  Hope that helps!